# Errors are encountered when trying to reinstall Samba

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have uninstalled Samba file server after I installed it. Now I want to install it again.

```
sudo pacman -S samba
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (9) boost-libs-1.78.0-2  ceph-libs-15.2.14-5  fmt-8.1.1-2  liburing-2.1-1  oath-toolkit-2.6.7-1  perl-parse-yapp-1.21-4  snappy-1.1.9-2  xmlsec-1.2.34-1
             samba-4.16.1-3

Total Installed Size:  132.06 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y    
(9/9) checking keys in keyring                                                                       [############################################################] 100%
(9/9) checking package integrity                                                                     [############################################################] 100%
(9/9) loading package files                                                                          [############################################################] 100%
(9/9) checking for file conflicts                                                                    [############################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
samba: /etc/ctdb/ctdb-crash-cleanup.sh exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/debug-hung-script.sh exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/debug_locks.sh exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/events/notification/README exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/functions exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/00.portmapper.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/10.status.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/20.nfs.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/30.nlockmgr.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/40.mountd.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/50.rquotad.check exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-checks.d/README exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/nfs-linux-kernel-callout exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/notify.sh exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/ctdb/statd-callout exists in filesystem
samba: /etc/sudoers.d/ctdb exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/cifsdd exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ctdb exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ctdb_diagnostics exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ctdbd exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ctdbd_wrapper exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/dbwrap_tool exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/dumpmscat exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/eventlogadm exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/gentest exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/locktest exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ltdbtool exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/masktest exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/mdsearch exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/mvxattr exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ndrdump exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/nmbd exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ntlm_auth exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/oLschema2ldif exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/onnode exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/pdbedit exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/ping_pong exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/profiles exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/regdiff exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/regpatch exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/regshell exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/regtree exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/sharesec exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/smbpasswd exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/smbstatus exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/smbtorture exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/testparm exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/wbinfo exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/bin/winbindd exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/dcerpc.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/dcerpc_samr.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/dcerpc_server.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ndr.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ndr_krb5pac.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ndr_nbt.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ndr_standard.pc exists in filesystem
samba: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/samdb.pc exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

This is the command I ran to install Samba and the output of the command. I have no idea how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have run `sudo pacman -Q samba`

Here is the output: `error: package 'samba' was not found`

Comment: Firstly, when installing packages in Arch Linux, `pacman -Syu <package>` That way, the system stays synced with the repos. Secondly, are you sure that `samba` was actually uninstalled? Add the output of `pacman -Q samba` to the question.

Comment: I updated it, and you will see that I got an error. It said that Samba was not found. I have also run `pacman -Syu samba` and get the same error.